# Excel Dependent Lists with duplicates

Tags: excel

My problem is the following:

I have multiple columns i want to make dependent lists of, but i have duplicates in the first 3 columns. I am able to make them dependent, but all the duplicates show up in the dropdown.

For Example:

[image]

You can see, the First column has duplicates and so does the second.

This is what i have tried.

1. Made the Product Category list as a List under Data validation using the uniques only.
2. Used the Offset, match formula to make the Sub-Product ID as a dependent list on what is selected in the cell before it for Product category.

When i do No. 2, say i chose A1 in the Product category, i end up getting 100,100 in the drop-down. I only want one iteration of 100 to be in the dependent dropdown.

Formula Used: `=OFFSET(Second!E5,MATCH(C3,Second!$D$6:$D$282,0),0,COUNTIF(Second!$D$6:$D$282,C3))`

Please help.

Comment: You should add the formulas you have used to your question. I would suggest to use `VLOOKUP`

Comment: I usually create pivots so that lists are ensured. Make sure you have the pivots refresh regularly. (tabular view, repeat all item labels)